# Static nested class can't use print

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a static nested class StatClass, the file name is Example.java

```
class OuterClass
{
    public static class StatClass 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello"); // This line doesn't work
        void pow()
        { System.out.println("Hello W");}
     }      
}
public class Example
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    OuterClass.StatClass statInner1 = new OuterClass.StatClass();
    statInner1.pow();      
    }
 }
```

The first println statement doesn't work in the static nested class i.e if its removed then the program compiles, although the println statement works when inside the pow() method, couldn't understand this

Comment: "This line doesn't work" because it's a statement outside a method.

Comment: Hint: before dealing with "inner classes" you maybe want to really cover the essential basics.

Comment: To be more precise: it's a statement *outside a block*.

Comment: @GhostCat ... which includes telling the OP correct terms: This is not an _inner class_. It simply is a _static nested class_. Inner classes are not static.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Uups. Correct; good catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in a normal class, you can't just put statements inside a class. You could put it in an initializer-block like this:

```
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Or in a constructor, or a method. Whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, very concise and apart from my question cleared some other things too.

Answer (score 1):

I am just uniting the two answers so far:

one option is a static block

```
class OuterClass
{
    public static class StatClass 
    {
         static {
        System.out.println("Hello"); // This line doesn't work
        }
        void pow()
        { System.out.println("Hello W");}
     }      
}
public class Example
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    OuterClass.StatClass statInner1 = new OuterClass.StatClass();
    statInner1.pow();     
    OuterClass.StatClass statInner2 = new OuterClass.StatClass();
    statInner2.pow();
    }
 }
```

The main difference is how the block is executed by the JVM. In the first case it is executed once during the class initialization. Then the output will be :

> Hello 
>   Hello W 
>   Hello W

Another option is initializer block in which case the code will be executed on each instantiation of the class.

```
class OuterClass
{
    public static class StatClass 
    {
     {
        System.out.println("Hello"); // This line doesn't work
        }
        void pow()
        { System.out.println("Hello W");}
     }      
}
public class Example
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    OuterClass.StatClass statInner1 = new OuterClass.StatClass();
    statInner1.pow();     
    OuterClass.StatClass statInner2 = new OuterClass.StatClass();
    statInner2.pow();
    }
 }
```

Then the output will be:

> Hello Hello W Hello Hello W

Comment: That's not a "static block": it's an instance initializer.

Comment: Now it is static :)

Comment: But you don't need to wrap it in a static block. An instance initializer would work too.

Comment: I am not sure the person that asks has any idea about the difference. He just wants to make it work.

Comment: But you don't *need to* wrap it in a static block, which is what you claim: other options (like an instance initializer or method) exist.

Comment: You are putting two much emphasize on the "need" word. I am neither born in US neither in UK "need". Probably I should have used "might"

Comment: Indeed: "You *could* use a static block". You *need to* put it in a block, of some description.

Comment: Why don't we just vote on each others answers instead talk about wording. Both things work. Of course there is a variation on  what they are doing but that is another story :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I disagree. Especially for beginners it is very important to be as precise as possible. Taking care of terms and sentences makes up for a good answer.

Comment: In the second example, maybe you forgot to remove the static keyword?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I agree with you. It is not about that the wording should not be corrected. It is about how you communicate the need for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Following statement is outside method that wont work

```
System.out.println("Hello"); // This line doesn't work
```

You have to wrap these statements inside static block as follows

```
static{
     System.out.println("Hello"); // This line will work
}
```

this block will execute when `JVM` create static instances.

Comment: "You have to use static block as follows" No, you don't; other options exist, depending upon requirements. "when JVM create static instances" the JVM doesn't create "static instances".

Comment: 1: At run time when JVM will see static blocks or static attributes it will allocate memory to all those static attributes and block. That's how it will execute in very beginning and will return with every instance of that class.

2: if JVM dont then who will?

whats wrong here dear ?

Comment: 1. But you don't need to use a static block. 2. There is no such thing as a "static instance": the JVM executes the static block when the class is loaded.

Comment: 1: why we dont need  static block? how you can write some statement outside method and inside class without static block ? 2: yeah that's what i meant unluckily my words doesn't match to yours.

Comment: @Andy take it easy on the "wording" element. Judging from your name english is native for you. Minor variations in language probably are not that visible for us compared to you. Don't be so focused on wording and imply that we have ment something different from you. That is not necessary the case.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov consider it from a non-English *reader's* perspective: they don't know that you meant "could" if you write "must". In whatever language (English, Russian, Java...) there are different terms for a reason.

Comment: @Andy I don' disagree on the "need" I disagree on the way you communicate the "need".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov so, do you want me not to point out the inaccuracy of the statement (meaning that readers are left wondering what you mean, or, worse, not realize it is inaccurate), or do you want me to make an assumption about what you really mean and correct it for you?

Comment: @Andy quite the opposite. You can do whatever you want in general , but if you ask of my humble opinion. The better way to put your statement is not "You have to use static block as follows" No, you don't; other options exist, depending upon requirements.  I am not sure that when you write it this way the other person even realize what you mean. Because he has no idea what you are talking about. The first time you wrote me "But you don't need to wrap it in a static block. " I had no idea what are you talking about and just after the second word exange I realize you are talking about the "need"

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Hello");
```

This does not work because,the control never goes to the line. Unless you define this inside a function and use the object you created to call it OR use the static block which does not require an object to call it OR an initializer block, it will not work. I hope that helps